# One to Many Relationship Design

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm in over my head on a database problem I'm taking on, even though it's quite simple. I'm used to using ORM's that take the backend SQL out of it for me, but that's not an option here.

I need to create a database that maps genres to multiple movies. For instance, action would be mapped to Terminator, Indiana Jones, and Rush Hour. Comedy would be mapped to The Big Lebowski and High Fidelity. I know in a truly robust solution a movie could have multiple genres, but let's just ignore that for now.

What is the best way to approach this so I can query a database by movie genre and receive a list of multiple movies?

Answer (score 1):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) teach the basics in sql.  I would definitely start there.  Then you probably want to search for a  a DDL (data definition language) tutorial to learn how to create tables properly - the syntax varies for each database. I did a quick search and this looks useful:  http://facility9.com/2010/07/postgresql-tutorial-creating-the-pagila-schema/.  You don't want to 'just ignore' the multiple genre issue, it's what makes databases useful.

For your specifics, essentially you need a **movie** table, a **genre** table, and a **movie-genre** table.  (You'll need bulk more, but these should cover the info in your question.)  Movie contains movie information in fields (title, year, director etc), one of which is a *primary key*.  The genre table, similarly contains genre information and also has a primary key.  The magic happens in the movie-genre table which has a primary key and 2 *foreign key* fields. One for the movie primary key, one for the genre primary key.  If, say, the Terminator movie's primary key is 1 and and the Action genre's primary key is 3, and Science Fiction genre primary key is 8 you would add a record for Terminator <-> Action by inserting 1, 3 into the movie-genre table, and add a Terminator <-> Science Fiction record by inserting 1, 8 into the table.

Your query would then look at this table to find what movies are in what genres (and vice versa), and use the other two tables to supply the wordy information.

Comment: w3schools has so many errors on their site (which they refuse to fix) that I would never recommend them for anything. The Postgres tutorial in the manual does a *much* better job in teaching the basics of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about joins then the simplest option to create a 3 column table like this:

UID, GENRE, FK_Movie

With FK_Movie obviously being the foreign key to the row in the Movie table. Using this approach you can actually attach multiple genres to the movie. To select the movies by genre simply "Select" the genre and do an inner join....

Comment: So I would just insert the same genre for as many times as there are movies for the genre? Is this any more efficient than doing a `SELECT * from movies where genre = x` query? I'm trying to avoid having to make massive queries to the database each time, as this supposed to load each time with a frequently accessed page.

Comment: Except you don't need the UID column.  Make the two columns genre and MovieId a composite primary Key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL fiddle demo for you:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9787b/3/0)

I agree with others, basics can be picked up on W3schools too:  [W3Schooles Learn SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Comment: w3schools is awful and full of errors. http://sqlzoo.com is much better (or the tutorial in the Postgres manual)

Comment: I disagree, w3 is my favorite quick reference for various functions.

Comment: Suit yourself, but you should be aware of all the errors on that site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many relationship. It is achieved by a lookup table with a field for the CategoryID and one for the MovieID. You should obtain the ID of the category you are interested in and then perform a simple one-many join type query on the lookup table and the movie table where Category="x".
    SELECT * FROM LookupTable as LT, Movies as M WHERE LT.Category = "x";

A simple lookup is all you need to get the CatID. The two queries can be combined, but I only show the second part here for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Create what is called an association or many-to-many table, with two columns, one for genre, and one with the MovieId

```
Create Table MovieGenres(
    Genre varchar(10),
    MovieId integer Not Null,
    Primary Key (Genre, MovieId)
)
```

Now every movie can have zero to many genres, and a genre can be used on zero to many movies.

Answer (score 0):

if you use EF you can do this as follow :

```
public class Movie
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // ... other movie properties ...

    public virtual Genre Genre{get; set;}
}



public class Genre
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    // if you want to Genre has at least on Movie, 
    // add [Required] attribute at top of Movies property
    public virtual List<Movie> Movies {get; set;}  // its used as FK
}
```

now in controller , for get Genre including it's Movies use code below :

```
public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
{
    var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Include("Movies").Single(g => g.Name == genre);

    return View(genreModel);
}
```

I hope its be useable --> Radmehr